# Connecting to Sybase using sqsh

Tags: linux, command-line, database-connection, sybase, sqsh

I am new to sybase.  I am trying to connect to the database using sqsh.

```
sqsh -Ddatabasename -Hservername -Uusername
or
sqsh -D databasename -H servername -U username
```

I get the following error.  server name not found in configuration file.  unknown host machine name.
I am trying to connect using the command line.  Wouldn't that bypass a config file.

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?)?  is `servername` the name of your Sybase server or the machine/host that Sybase is running on? (if the former, try replacing `-H` with `-S`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on Linux and I use sqsh like this:

```
sqsh -I /etc/freetds/freetds.conf -Smyserver  -Uknb -Pverysecret -Dmydb
```

-D  argument is optional

and in the `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`
there is an entry

```
[myserver]
        host = 123.456.78.90
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.2
        client charset = UTF-8
```

This used to work for many years. Right now I have some connectivity problems (segfaults), but this can be due to library configuration issues on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use the hostname. Use -S for the servername , which must be defined in the interfaces file (or sql.ini file). You can leave the database name out.